# Enable File sharing in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, file-management, network-shares, file-sharing

There seems to be a problem in my Windows Vista.. In the network and sharing centre only the network discovery is visible. I cant find a option for file sharing as mentions in other websites. There is no folder sharing option on any folder.

Can someone please tell me how to enable file sharing in my Windows Visa? i cant share any of my file in the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Explorer go to Organize > Folder and Search Options > View > Use Sharing Wizard (it may say Use Simple File Sharing, I'm on 7 so I can't double check.)

Then you can right click on the folder you wish to share and select properties and share it from there.